# Split function on [16]

Tags: groovy, split

I'm trying to split the data from the variable as given below:

```
string data = [16]

string [] temp = null

temp.split("\\[");
```

I am struck here, how do I split two square brackets and get values 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want the String "16" or the Integer 16, so I've shown both below

```
String data = "[16]"

assert "16" == data[1..-2]
assert 16 == data[1..-2].toInteger()
```

FYI, the code above will work for a String of any length enclosed in `[]`

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of research gave me this option to replace all square brackets

```
string.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","");
```

Any other suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Comment: When writing regular expressions in groovy, save yourself the double-escapes and use [Slashy Syntax](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString#StringsandGString-SlashyStringliterals) - which looks like `string.replaceAll(/\[|\]/, '')`